# How Can I Edit MP3 File's Lyrics and Album Cover Img Using Python?

Tags: python, mp3, eyed3

I want to use eyed3 on python to edit lyrics and cover img, but I can't find a way to do it.
Do I have to use a other module, or is there a way to edit with eyed3?

PS. I used eyed3 to edit lyrics like this, but it didn't work...

```
import eyed3

mp3_file = 'file path.mp3'
lyrics = 'Hello, World!'

file_edit = eyed3.load(mp3_file)
file_edit.tag.lyrics.set = lyrics
file_edit.tag.save()
```

(This is the way that I found on the Internet)